# Biblatex format for oral talks (needs to print conference and date)

Tags: biblatex

I want to use biblatex for an appendix that contains a list of presentations given. I want to add entries for oral presentations, where there are no corresponding proceedings.

E.g. the output should look like:

> Agent Smith (1st June 2010), ‘Entangled in the Matrix’, *Cyberwhatever Symposium*, Berlin

The problem is, there seems no template which gets the fields right. The closest match would be `@inproceedings`:

```
@inproceedings{author2010title,
  AUTHOR   = {Smith, Agent},
  TITLE    = {{Entangled in the Matrix}},
  BOOKTITLE= {Cyberwhatever Symposium},
  ADDRESS  = {Berlin},
  DATE     = {2010-06-01}
}
```

Which is rendered with an `in:`

> Agent Smith (1st June 2010), ‘Entangled in the Matrix’, in: *Cyberwhatever Symposium*, Berlin

If I use `@article`:

```
@article{author2010title,
  AUTHOR   = {Smith, Agent},
  TITLE    = {{Entangled in the Matrix}},
  JOURNAL  = {Cyberwhatever Symposium},
  ADDRESS  = {Berlin},
  DATE     = {2010-06-01}
}
```

The address is dropped:

> Agent Smith (1st June 2010), ‘Entangled in the Matrix’, *Cyberwhatever Symposium*

I don't want to modify the formatting of `article` or `inproceedings`, because they will affect a lot of already correctly typeset published entries.

Comment: If you use Biber, you can also define a custom type `talk` and customise it exactly to your needs. Would you be interested in that?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a compromise:

```
@misc{author2010title,
  AUTHOR       = {Smith, Agent},
  TITLE        = {{Entangled in the Matrix}},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {Cyberwhatever Symposium},
  LOCATION     = {Berlin},
  DATE         = {2010-06-01}
}
```

This puts the title in italics instead of inverted commas, and the conference title is non-italic:

> Agent Smith (1st June 2010), *Entangled in the Matrix*, Cyberwhatever Symposium, Berlin